# How to write published section of a class with "Property" keyword in Delphi Prism?

Tags: .net, class, properties, publish, delphi-prism

I have a derived class with published section. However, the keyword published is not recognized by the compiler and anything below it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the class:

```
TTrendChart = class(Panel)
private
  fCount:integer;
  fColors:array[0..7] of Color;
  fNames:array[0..7] of string;
  fMinText:string;
  fMaxText:string;
  fShowNames:Boolean;
  fMaxTextWidth:integer;
  data:ArrayList;
  Indexer:integer;
  chartRect:Rectangle;
  fWidth:integer;
  fHeight:integer;
  firstTime:Boolean;
  method  GetColors(Index:integer):Color;
  method  SetColors(Index:integer; const value :Color);
  method  GetNames(Index:integer):string;
  method  SetNames(Index:integer; const value: string);
  method  SetCount(const value : integer);
  method  rShowNames(const value : Boolean);
  method  SetMaxText(const value:string);
  method  SetMinText(const value:string);
  method  RecalcChartRect;
protected
  method  Resize; override;
  method  Paint; override;
public
  constructor (AOwner : TComponent); override;
  //destructor Destroy; override;
  method  PlotPoints(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8:real);
  method  ClearChart;
  method  Print;
  property TrendColors[Index1:integer]: TColor read GetColors write SetColors;
  property TrendNames[index1:integer]: string read GetNames write SetNames;
published
  property TrendCount: Integer read fCount write SetCount default 8;
  property ShowNames: Boolean read fShowNames write rShowNames default true;
  property MaxText:string16 read fMaxText write SetMaxText;
  property MinText:string16 read fMinText write SetMinText;
  property Align;
  property Alignment;
  property BevelInner;
  property BevelOuter;
  property BevelWidth;
  property DragCursor;
  property DragMode;
  property Enabled;
  property Caption;
  property Color;
  property Ctl3D;
  property Font;
  property Locked;
  property ParentColor;
  property ParentCtl3D;
  property ParentFont;
  property ParentShowHint;
  property PopupMenu;
  property ShowHint;
  property TabOrder;
  property TabStop;
  property Visible;

  property Click;
  property DblClick;
  property DragDrop;
  property DragOver;
  property EndDrag;
  property Enter;
  property Exit;
  property MouseDown;
  property MouseUp;
  property MouseMove;
  property Resize;
end;
```

I can't seem to find answer online regarding this issue. I thought it should have worked as it is written. Compiler keeps saying **"Colon ':' expected"** for each line with property keyword following the line **property MinText:string16 read fMinText write SetMinText;**

Any help will be appreciated. Thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like 'published' in .NET, so that code make no sense at all.
To increase visibility you need to override that element with the new visibility. All details for the visibility options are explained here: http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Class_Member_Visibility_Levels

Comment: That's what I thought. So, then my real question is this. How do you inherit from a component and their events or methods if property keyword is not allowed?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. When you inherit from a class, all their public members are automatically inherited. You don't need to take any action for that.When you want to open up visibility of protected members to public, you simply override them with the new intended visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi, when you define a property, you have to give it a name, and a type:

```
property Resize: Boolean;
```

Comment: If I don't remember wrong (from Delphi) then `property PropName;` is just changing/increasing visibility level of an inherited property -- I don't remember if Delphi Prism supports that syntax.

Comment: Well, in any case the compiler is saying that a colon is expected, try putting in the data type anyway?

Comment: @McKay Is there even a keyword published for Delphi Prism? I don't understand. There is apparently no information available on this feature online for Delphi Prism. MSDN library doesn't seem to mention it. It does, however, show how to create properties within a class in C#. I removed the word published and compiler is raising other errors now.

Comment: @digitalanalog I think Prism neither supports that visibility-increasing syntax nor the [visibility](http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Class_Member_Visibility_Levels) "published" since both concepts don't exist in .NET

Comment: @ springy76 and McKay I am also looking around for example projects and code and I am not finding it.